# Ghost title bar in Qt programs

Tags: unity, 13.04, qt

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and I guess ever since I updated it from 12.10 I've been having a problem with qt applications (VLC and K3B, specifically). Sometimes, when I open them, the title bar doesn't work. It is unclickable, so when I try to double click it (to maximise it), or drag it, or click on one of the control buttons, the window simply minimizes. The solution I found was to `Ctrl+Super+Up`, so the window is maximized and the title bar disapears. If I restore the window again the title bar works normally again.

Here are some prints:

[image: Ghost bar in VLC]
[image: Maximized VLC]
[image: Same problem with K3b]

Answer (score 1):

I have few suggestion you could try. 
1. Check if the problem persists with other users created on your PC/Laptop
2. If the programs are working well on other user accounts, probably it has something to do with you misconfiguration of your profile.

What I would usually do is re-install unity:

1. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-services`
2. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it has something to do with your windows decorations. Do you have Compiz installed? If so I would suggest re-installing, or at least checking your `window decoration` settings.

Re-install ↓

> apt-get update
>
> apt-get install compiz-core
>
> apt-get install compiz

Hope this helps...Good luck!